# Getting an entry's tags

Tags: plugin-development, tags, models

I'm trying to find a way to get tag data from a Model. Currently, I have a template that makes use of tags in an entry like this:

```
Codes: {% for tag in entry.codes %} {{ tag.title }}; {% endfor %}
```

When I create this template, I also need to send some of the data (specifically this data) to an API. Assuming I have an `$entry` object, how do I iterate through the tags that I need, or get an array with all the tags associated with an entry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `$entry`, you should be able to get the tags by the field name, (`codes`, in your case).

```
$tags = $entry->codes;
foreach($tags as $tag)
{
    echo "<li>".$tag->title."</li>";
}
```